# Turning off figures in latex completely (without placeholders)

Tags: graphics, floats, draft

Is there an easy method to compile a LaTeX document ignoring contents of `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` blocks altogether?

I am looking for an equivalent for `draft` and `demo` options (as in `\documentclass[demo]{article}` or `\usepackage[draft]{graphics}`) that will ignore `figure` environment completely. Specifically, don't want to see any placeholders nor figure captions, just continuous text.

Is there a way to do the same thing for `table` environments?

Comment: You don't want to keep any space there?

Comment: Maybe try: \renewenvironment{figure}{}{}

Comment: @Sigur No, not really. It is for purpose of text editing - I have quite some figures in my paper and it would be a great option to save both on ink and paper.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay It would have worked if figures had no captions, but it just throws a bunch of errors: `Package caption Error: \caption outside float. \caption`

Comment: I believe that Memoir has an MSS (or similarly named) option which duplicates a typewritten manuscript --- it may also turn off all graphics (or maybe it moves them all to the end).

Comment: @WillAdams Could you give some link/more specific reference? I found the Memoir class, but after short search I can't find the feature you mention in the documentation.

Comment: Try adding \let\caption\relax

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `endfloat`, telling it that it shouldn't process the delayed floats:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%% Remove the next two lines if you want the figures at their place    
\usepackage[figuresonly,nolists,nomarkers]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\processdelayedfloats}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}% mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Whatever}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Whatever}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{table}[htp]
A table
\caption{Something}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

If you want to also omit tables, remove the `figuresonly` option.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, that is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. I was not not familiar with `endfloat` package at all.

Comment: This doesn't seem to remove longtabu environment

Comment: @raffamaiden This excludes figure and table environments, yours is a different problem.

Comment: @egreg how can I remove longtabu and longtable environments? `\renewenvironment{longtabu}{}{}` does not work. The table is still there but badly formatted

Comment: @raffamaiden Look at the comment package.

Comment: @egreg `\includecomment{tabu}` does not work either. The table is still there

Comment: Thanks anyway @egreg, here is my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402956/make-table-invisibles

Comment: It seems to me figure labels then go undefined ?

Comment: @Joce Quite likely, but what would be the reason for referencing non-existent objects? On the other hand, it's not difficult to process endfloats and then suppress the pages in the final PDF.

Comment: @egreg Yes that's what I've done (`pdfjam`). The reason is if you need to submit separately text and figures to a journal, e.g. They do exist, all be it in a separate file.

Comment: Can we apply this for `tabular` as well?

Comment: @alper Of course not.