# Make table invisibles

Tags: floats, longtable, tabu, longtabu, endfloat

I have a dissertation with lots of `longtable` and `tabu` environments.

`longtable` are on their own, while `tabu` are wrapped inside `table` environments.

I want something to put in the preamble of the document that makes the tables (both `longtable` and `tabu`) invisible. That suppresses them, like those environments were not there.

I have to do that because I have to give the dissertation to a person that needs to edit it, and I have to convert to Word

Surronding every table with the `comment` environment is not an option, because I have tons of tables.

I tried the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224990/turning-off-figures-in-latex-completely-without-placeholders/224999?noredirect=1#comment1003929_224999) but it doesn't work. That solution is to put

```
\usepackage[figuresonly,nolists,nomarkers]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\processdelayedfloats}{}
```

in the preamble. I tried with:

```
\renewenvironment{tabu}[1]{}{}
```

But the text of the table is still there unformatted. I assume because that command substitute \begin{tabu} with nothing and \end{tabu} with nothing, leaving the text inside

then I tried:

```
\renewenvironment{tabu}[1]{\comment}{\endcomment}
```

After loading the `comment`package, and the file does not compile

Can you help me please?

Comment: After `\usepackage{comment}` do `\excludecomment{longtabu}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Package `comment`

The `comment` package offers `\excludecomment`. It can be (mis)used to disable an environment. However, it does not overwrite the `\end{...}` part, thus the following example clears the end code part of the environment explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{longtable}
\let\endlongtable\relax

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{longtable}{ll}
  Answer: & 42
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Package `version`

Macro `\excludeversion` of package `version` also redefines the `\end` part of the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{version}
\excludeversion{longtable}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{longtable}{ll}
  Answer: & 42
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

However, the documentation of package `version` (inside `version.sty`) warns:

> Very long sections of excluded text might cause  a `TeX capacity
>   exceeded' error.

## Package `versions`

Package `versions` (with suffix `s`) claims to have solved some of the problems of `version`, including the memory issue:

> · Large passages don't fill main memory when excluded. (`s` in
>   `versions` means    *safe*!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{versions}
\let\longtable\relax % Removes warning
\excludeversion{longtable}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{longtable}{ll}
  Answer: & 42
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The package is more verbose (messages on the console). `\longtable` is disabled explicitly before `\excludeversion` to avoid a warning, that environment table was previously defined.