# Turning off tabularx in latex completely

Tags: tabularx, draft

Is there an easy method to compile a LaTeX document ignoring contents of

```tex
\begin{table}[t!]
    \begin{tabularx}
    ...
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

blocks altogether?

example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}% mock text
%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{singlespace}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        % \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{bss}
          \hline
          Alpha     & Beta     & Gamma     \\ \hline
          0         & 2        & 4         \\ \hline
          1         & 3        & 5         \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{singlespace}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Here if possible with global definition I want ot hide tabular block.

Related to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224999/127048

Comment: 1. `\begin{singlespace}` around `table` makes no sense; use `\singlespacing` inside it. 2. A `table` environment without at least one `\caption` doesn't really make sense. 3. You likely want to hide `table`, not the inner `tabularx`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you, should I have `\singlespacing` inside `table` or `tabularx`?

Comment: Inside `table`.